# Putting space between column elements in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]I have two buttons below which are placed one above other:

```
<Button 
                    onPress = {() =>{this.toggleModal(); }}
                    color="#512D67"
                    title="Submit" 
                    />
                <Button 
                    onPress = {() =>{this.toggleModal(); }}
                    color="#c0c0c0"
                    title="Cancel" 
                    />
```

These are placed without any space between them. How can I put space between them( margin and padding not working)?

Thank You!

Comment: Buttons are placed top to bottom without any space between them. How do you place an empty space between two divisions in html, it is just like that.

Comment: wrap it some View element then add styles

Comment: I am using padding an margin but they aren't working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button in react native doesnt take a style prop, you will have to wrap it with a View and add the styles to the view

```
             <View style={{paddingBottom:20}}>
              <Button 
                onPress = {() =>{this.toggleModal(); }}
                color="#512D67"
                title="Submit" 
                />
              </View>
```

Comment: This is not working as well. Whatever I am using doesn't adds space between these buttons.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/DsegRo9w! can you check this ?

Comment: Your snack link is not reachable

Comment: snack.expo.io/DsegRo9w! the exclamation is also part of the url

Comment: Although it is working, but putting a single element inside view just to put padding doesn't seem to be a good idea? Can you explain why I can't use paddingBottom in Button style itself?

Comment: Button doesnt take a style, thats the issue

Comment: The other option would be to have your custom button component with a View wrap and pass the styles

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code below, it should solve your problem.

```
    <View style={{ marginVertical: 20 }}>
      <Button color="#512D67" title="Submit" />
    </View>
    <View>
      <Button color="#c0c0c0" title="Cancel" />
    </View>
```

Basically you just add margin vertically to the button with the help of View wrap.